# Adding a class to "this" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the `.focused` class to any clicked link from `nav` menu.

The short script I wrote isn't working. Could anyone tell me why please?

```js
$("nav").on('click', '*', function() {
  $(this).addClass('focused');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <h1>Menu:</h1> <br>
  <a href="/tests/add-new-test-link">Add link</a>
  <a href="/tests/run-tests">Run tests</a>
  <a href="/tests/reports-history">Test reports history</a>
  <a href="/tests/links-list">Links list</a>
</nav>
```

I tried to check what is under `this` by `console.log(this)` and `console.log($(this))` but nothing shows there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `'click', '*',` shouldnt this be `'click', 'a',`

Comment: Because you're redirecting to _that_ page?

Comment: you scripts works, but i guess it "dont" because when you click on a link, you redirect to another page.

Comment: Works fine when you disable the navigation https://jsfiddle.net/0artbccn/

Comment: Or click on "Menu", which is not a link.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works but your link will redirect by default. If you prevent the default behavior by using [**preventDefault**](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) you can see it work as expected.

However, that might not make sense if you want your links to actually redirect automatically. On the other hand if you want to use them simply as menus to load other data on the page based on the `href` value you can use the below and then process the link manually.

```js
$("nav").on('click', '*', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('focused');
});
```

```css
.focused{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <h1>Menu:</h1> <br>
  <a href="/tests/add-new-test-link">Add link</a>
  <a href="/tests/run-tests">Run tests</a>
  <a href="/tests/reports-history">Test reports history</a>
  <a href="/tests/links-list">Links list</a>
</nav>
```